# Excel (Mac) Formula - Group Like Items and Search Each Row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a really huge excel file (14mb) that I need to remove certain rows based on criteria and can't figure out what the formula would look like to accomplish what I need.

Here's an example of the data:

```
ID             TYPE          MATCH
12345          CAR            
12345          TRUCK
54321          PLANE
54321          BOAT
12345          BOAT
```

For this example, what I need to do is group all duplicative IDs and then search through each of the rows of that group to see if one of them is a car.

The output should look like this:

```
ID             TYPE          MATCH
12345          CAR           TRUE  
12345          TRUCK         TRUE
54321          PLANE         FALSE
54321          BOAT          FALSE
12345          BOAT          TRUE
```

Since ID 12345 has a car in the group, all of those rows get marked as true. Likewise, as 54321 does not have a car in the group, all of those rows get marked as false.

I want to do this entirely using a formula as I need to modify the search parameters to pair down the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of your question is like this:

[image]

and this would be the formula:

edit:

If you just want TRUE/FALSE you can enter this in C2 (version w/o LET):

```
=BYROW(A$2:A$6;LAMBDA(rowID;SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FILTER(B$2:B$6;A$2:A$6=rowID);"Car")))>0))
```

.. and without spilling:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FILTER(B$2:B$6;A$2:A$6=A2);"Car")))>0
```

edit 2 as a fast and simple solution (not optimized):

create a helper column E to list all IDs that has “Car” as type starting with
E2:

```
 =IF(B2="Car";A2;0)
```

assuming “0” is not a valid ID as dummy for the other rows.

In column C try to match ID with helper column:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2;E$2:E$6;0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I can't get this formula to work. Excel throws a formula error. Also, the real data set is hundreds of thousands of rows and I need to first group all the duplicate values and then check another column to see if a value exists (much like my example only quite a bit larger). Your output looks correct, but I only want the True/False column (F).

Comment: Also, LET does not seem to be a function available on the Mac

Comment: The screenshot is from iPad, so I assumed it should work on Mac as well. I forgot to mention may need to replace ; with , due to regional settings. I added/edited the formula for TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It appears LET is only for beta users on the Mac right now. I've got 16.63.1 but LET is not a thing. Would it be possible to edit/update without using LET so I could try it out?

Comment: The last formula is the “simplest” which you need to add for each row, in case BYROW is also not supported.

Comment: I'm so sorry but it seems BYROW is not available, nor is FILTER. I checked that SUMPRODUCT, ISNUMBER, and SEARCH are all available.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention that I'm not looking for this formula to remove any rows. My example showing the final output was just an explanation of what I'm going to do. I need the output to look like the example I posted that says ("The output should look like this"). All I need is the True/False for every row. I can take it from there. I updated the original post so it's not confusing. Sorry about that.

Comment: At this moment I don’t have any other idea without involving some kind of helper column. By the way, I had a look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759 the current Excel for Mac is supported

Comment: If I need a helper column that's totally fine. I just need to solve this. MS's website says it's available but it's really not and when you dig into the forums there's lots of people complaining. Apparently these "newer" functions are only available to Office 365 subscribers on the beta channel (and even then it's rolling out sporadically for Mac users).

Comment: Have a look on the edit.

Comment: Thank you. That does exactly what I was looking to do. Really appreciate your efforts!